# C program concurrency with pthread

Tags: c, multithreading, concurrency, pthreads

I am doing a review with my professor's lecture note. I got this question when I reached the concurrency section:

 in the slide, professor gave two examples of using pthread (one is good example and the other is bad.). But I dont understand why there is a difference between them.

 here is the good example:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <pthread.h> 
void *get_rand_num(void *args) { 
  int *nump = malloc(sizeof(int)); 
  srand(pthread_self()); 
  *nump = rand(); 
  return nump; 
} 
int main() { 
  pthread_t tid; 
  void *ptr = NULL; 
  pthread_create(&tid, NULL, get_rand_num, NULL); 
  pthread_join(tid, &ptr); 
  printf("Random number: %d\n", * (int *) ptr); 
  return 0; 
}
```

And the bad example is

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <pthread.h> 
void *get_rand_num(void *args) { 
  int num; 
  srand(pthread_self()); 
  num = rand(); 
  return &num; 
} 
int main() { 
  pthread_t tid; 
  void *ptr = NULL; 
  pthread_create(&tid, NULL, get_rand_num, NULL); 
  pthread_join(tid, &ptr); 
  printf("Random number: %d\n", * (int *) ptr); 
  return 0; 
}
```

Anyone can understand these two examples please explain to me why the bad one is different from the first one, and why it is not good?

Thank you

allan

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The bad example returns a pointer to a local variable. This is always a bad idea, because local variables die when the function returns. This is no problem specific to multi-threaded programs, but aggravated because threads get one stack per thread, which is deallocated after the `pthread_join`. While you often get lucky in single-threaded programming and can use the pointer immediately after the function's return, the whole segment containing the old thread's stack might have gone back to the operating system in the bad example and accesses would produce segmentation faults.

The first example is also not very good since it produces a memory leak.

Comment: Thank you, I think I got it! By the way, in the first example, did you mean it should be improved by add a line to free the memory that was allocated?  such as `free(nump)`? where do you think I should put this line in the program? should I put it before the `pthread_join()`?

Comment: Technically, since the program is short-lived and the memory is automatically reclaimed by the OS on program termination, there's no memory leak, just bad practice.

Comment: @AllanJiang: No, absolutely not. Always follow the simple rule: `malloc`, use the memory, and when you are finished, `free`. Put it after the `printf` call.

Answer (score 1):

In the bad case, your return &num, where num is a local variable on the stack, which is only valid during the function scope.  Once you return, it is no longer valid.

Answer (score 0):

The bad case returns a pointer to a bit of the stack - like a bird that has flown out of the window long time ago!

But if it works - you are going to have a very very random number - a bit better that sallting the random number gerenrator with the id of the thread!

Comment: Actually, it might be less random because it directly refers to a place in memory accessible by another program (attack vector).

Comment: Glad a person has a bit of humor around here. Either way I could have a good guess at that ***random*** number

Comment: Humorous indeed; just pointing out something interesting. :-)